# Can we add a "this question is opinion based" option to the "first questions" review queue?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons, comments, opinion-based, review-queue

Currently, when I go to review a first question asked by a new user, I have three options. I can write a custom comment, or I can use a pre-made comment that recommends the user to clarify their question or only ask one question. What I tend to see far more often than the latter two options, is a question that is opinion based.

So I want to know if we can get a pre-made comment to let the user know that their question is opinion based and to recommend an edit to them.